# "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" message while running a program with the Terminal

Tags: 20.04

I have a problem when running a certain program. The execution works perfectly fine, but there is an additional line that appears before the execution : Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key

Is there a way to prevent this message to appear ?
With some research, I tried different commands :

- Try `xhost +local:` before running
- Change the variable DISPLAY with the export command
- Check if the XAUTHORITY environment exists (it does not)

Do you have any other suggestions that I can try ?

Comment: `xauth list` and `hostnamectl status` please.

Comment: The program executable (In my case `octave`), is trying to be smart and pipe the internal X11 display through ssh to the remote computer, and fails.  Are you passing the `-X` parameter to ssh?  Take that off, and try passing the `-Y` as in: `ssh -Y youruser@yourhostname`, or if that fails try running octave from a logged in user that has access to the primary monitor display.

Answer (score 3):

This indicates a permission Problem or simply a wrong magic cookie ..

- what works for me: `xhost + 192.168.1.2` for virtual boxes  , then in the virtual machine : `DISPLAY=192.168.1.1:0.0 dbus-run my-x11-program`
- the **MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE** is stored in the file **.Xauthority** of the user who is running the desktop
- **you might have an already wrong-filled .Xauthority ?**
- **you could also just "steal" this one (transfer via ssh) or copy on
  localhost , sometimes `sudo` works , and `su` not**
- when everything fails: run via ssh with e.g `ssh -YXC myuser@the-machine "the-command"`
- if you encounter failures concerning `MPI_init()` from **openMPI**, you should read the [mpirun-gui section from the manual](http://open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-gui) there is [another thread in the SE community describing what MPI_Init() it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691491/the-use-of-mpi-init)

Comment: What if i don't have an .Xauthority file? Everything is local in my case, I'm just running programs on my local machine and getting that error message. Also ubuntu 20.04.
The programs that cause this are ones that call MPI_Init(), if that helps. Paraview for example.

Comment: uuhm "MPI_init()" is a environment setup function from a clustering mechanism (openMPI.. if it is from the **REAL** MPI ) , [you can use strace](https://doc-links-manual-howto.github.io/pub/wiki.html#sys%3Alinux%3Adebug%3Astrace) to see what is going on , 

also you should read the mpirun-gui https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-gui on that topic and adjust your xhost/DISPLAY variables , they  have a good example

a good explanation on mpi_init is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691491/the-use-of-mpi-init