# “Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key” message while running a program with the Terminal

Tags: command-line, nvidia

I have the same problem discussed here:
["Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" message while running a program with the Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238389/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-message-while-running-a-program-with-the-termin)

I already tried the solutions reported there
Any suggestion is welcome

hostnamectl status

```
   Static hostname: VivoBook
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: a8080c018741443d97105241722bc82d
           Boot ID: f397f248ea584fe2907e01ef63d4b6f2
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-33-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

xauth list

```
VivoBook/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  134556a706e919cf2768b373cbf77da0
#ffff#5669766f426f6f6b#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  134556a706e919cf2768b373cbf77da0
```

echo $DISPLAY

```
:1
```

nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    561MiB /  4042MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2413      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            79MiB |
|    0      3118      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           249MiB |
|    0      3388      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         204MiB |
|    0      3877      G   ...uest-channel-token=14869638892127264724    13MiB |
|    0      5803      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
|    0      5810      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
|    0      5853      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No. I can launch graphical apps without any issue and I get the message running a program without any graphical interface. It is just a fortran program compiled with gfortran and mpi.